# How do you remove a custom extension?

Tags: arcobjects, extensions

For example: you run the DesktopExtensionCS2010 sample that comes with the SDK, having it open arcCat at startup.

Now whenever I open ArcCat the extensions are there. I can uncheck them but I want to get rid of them (without hacking the registry).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using ArcGIS 10.0, use the [ESRIRegAsm Utility](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004n6000000), for example:

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\ESRIRegAsm.exe" /p:desktop /u "C:\Test\MyAssembly.dll"
```

For 9.3.x and earlier you can use [regasm.exe](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/9826f81b-278c-49cc-a912-ab8d86f5e91e.htm#UsingRegasm) like so:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe "C:\Test\MyAssembly.dll" /unregister
```

You would enter one of those commands in the Windows command prompt (Start->Programs->Accessories->Command Prompt).

Answer (score 2):

If the extension is bundled as part of an add-in, you should be able to use the add-in manager to remove them, or simply delete it from the [well-known folder](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Advanced_add_in_concepts/0001000004n7000000/). If you use add-in manager note that the add-in can remain in memory until you've restarted your app.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove a extension, the general way, is to go via regasm/ESRIRegAsm Utility;

However, if you yourself have installed it, when trying out the samples, the easiest way would be to open the solution in Visual Studio, and then clean the solution.

This will deregister the dlls.